# Mips elements of an array

Tags: assembly, mips

I am given:

$a0 = adress of an array

$a1 = size of that array

I have to return:

$v0 = max

$v1 = position of max (1 based indexing)

My code works as intended for array size = 0 but fails every other test by returning max = {first element}, position = 1 every single time.

```
maxAndArg:

        li $v0, -2147483648       # $v0(MAX) is the smallest negative number 
        li $v1, 0                 # $v1(POSITION) starts from zero
        li $t3, 0                 # $t3(i in a normal language) will be used to loop
        li $t4, 0                 # $t4 will be used to show the position in the array 
L1:

        beq $t3,$a1,EXIT          # if (i = arrsize) goto EXIT

        sll $t4,$t4,2             # $t4 = $t4 * 4

        add $t5,$a0,$t4           # $t5 now has the ADDRESS of the $t4 element

        lw $t5,0($t5)             # $t5 now has the VALUE of the $t4 element

        ble $v0,$t5,L2            # if (max =< a[$t4]) goto L2

        srl $t4,$t4,2             # $t4 = $t4 / 4 (Original value)

        addi $t4,$t4,1            # $t4 = $t4 + 1

        addi $t3,$t3,1            # $t3 = $t3 + 1 ((i++))


        j L1
L2:

        add $v0,$t5,0             # max = $t5

        add $v1,$t3,1             # position = $t3
EXIT:

        jr     $ra                #return
```

Comment: I don't know MIPS but looks like your code executes `ble $v0,$t5,L2` because initially $v0 is 'the smallest possible' and never gets back to L1, it exits.

Answer (score 0):

When the execution enters `L2`, it doesn't return to the loop, instead it just exists at the first iteration. You can either jump back after entering `L2`, using a label after the `ble` instruction, or you can change it to `bgt` and skip code like an `if` would work in a higher-level language.

```
    ...
    lw $t5,0($t5)             # $t5 now has the VALUE of the $t4 element
    bgt $v0,$t5,L2            # if (max > a[$t4]) goto L2

    # this below will only be executed if a[$t4] >= max
    add $v0,$t5,0             # max = $t5
    add $v1,$t3,1             # position = $t3

L2:
    # else or finally, continuing loop...
    srl $t4,$t4,2             # $t4 = $t4 / 4 (Original value)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you I will add a label after the ble line and jump there after L1, that should work.